# Convert a numpy array to an image

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jpeg

I have a numpy array representing a jpg, not as file. Therefore I have to directly process the array. I want to save these data into a file so that I can watch it with a usual jpg viewer. Usually I can do that with

```
pl = pylab.imshow(ds.pixel_array, cmap=pylab.cm.bone)
```

but the image information is coded in jpg2000, therefore this approach failed. I tried therefore pgmagick:

```
tmp = pgmagick.Image(ds.pixel_array)
logging.info("Info I")
pl = pgmagick.Blob()
tmp.write(pl, 'GRAY')
```

but unfortunately this fails, too, with the error that the numpy-array can not be converted into a pgmagick-image. Is there another way to convert the jpg2000-coded information into PIL-able information?

Update:
Running the following line

```
jpg_bytes = ds.pixel_array.astype('uint8').tostring()
```

leads to the following error:

```
Data type not understood by NumPy: format='uint12', PixelRepresentation=0, BitsAllocated=12
```

Edit: The complete function:

```
def convert(self, inputpic, outputpic = "", force = False):
        if not inputpic or not os.path.isfile(inputpic):
            logging.critical("No valid input filename entered, or input file not found. Input filename was " + inputpic)
            return INT_ERROR
        else:
            input_clean = self.cleanEnding(inputpic)
            if not outputpic:
                outputpic = input_clean + ".jpg"
            print "Output pic is " + outputpic
            if os.path.isfile(outputpic + ".jpg") and force is False:
                logging.critical("Output file is already there, don't want to overwrite it! Output filename was " + outputpic)
            else:
                if outputpic[:-4] is not ".jpg":
                    outputpic = outputpic + ".jpg"
                try:
                    ds = dicom.read_file(inputpic, force=True)
                except InvalidDicomError:
                    logging.critical("File " + inputpic + " is not a dicom file!")
                    return INT_ERROR
                #try:
                #    pl = pylab.imshow(ds.pixel_array, cmap=pylab.cm.bone)
                #except:
                try:
                    logging.info("Decoding starts now")
                    jpg_bytes = "".join(chr(x) for x in ds.pixel_array)
                    logging.info("Test I")
                    jpg_bytes = ds.pixel_array.astype('uint8').tostring()
                    logging.warning("Trying to decode it with pgmagick")
                    im = pgmagick.Image.open(io.BytesIO(jpg_bytes))
                    logging.info("Decoding successfull")
                    #logging.info("Info I")
                    #pl = pgmagick.Blob()
                    #tmp.write(pl, 'GRAY')
                except Exception as e:
                    logging.critical("Critical error happened during imshow() with file " + inputpic + " with the following error: " + str(e))
                    return INT_ERROR
                if not os.path.isfile("tmp.png"):
                    pylab.savefig("tmp.png")
                else:
                    logging.critical("tmp.png is already in this folder, maybe a failed cleanup? Stopping!")
                    return INT_ERROR
                im = Image.open("tmp.png")
                bg = Image.new("RGB", im.size, (255,255,255))
                bg.paste(im, (0,0), im)
                bg.save(outputpic[:-4], quality=95)
                os.remove("tmp.png")
        return INT_SUCCESS
```

with inputpic as a dicom file.
The error in the logging file turns up after the first logging.info (`logging.info("Decoding starts now")`), therefore I assume that the error is thrown from the second line, after the third line is not in the log file anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you just write it as a binary file without involving PIL? Have you tried the io from scikit image?

Comment: Note that you can't use `is` to compare strings, so `if outputpic[:-4] is not ".jpg"` will not do what you expect. Use `==` / `!=`: `if outputpic[:-4] != ".jpg"`.

Comment: Also, if you use `logging.exception` instead of `logging.critical` you'll get a stack trace along with the error.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `pixel_array` is an array of bytes which represent the JPEG-encoded image (the first four bytes - the magic number - will be `FF D8 FF E0` if this is the case).

You can convert the numpy array to a byte string using:

```
jpg_bytes = ds.pixel_array.astype('uint8').tostring()
```

And you can load a byte string using:

```
import io
from pgmagick import Image

im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(jpg_bytes))
```

**Edit**: I missed the "jpg2000" bits, so:

- pgmagick can load jpg2000 files and the code above will work without issue.
- The magic number of jpg2000 files is `0000 000C 6A50 2020 0D0A 870A`.

Comment: I have the data as a numpy array, not as a file, as stated in my question. Furthermore I have the problem that PIL is not able to handle jpg2000-compressed data, as also stated in the question, therefore rendering it useless for me.

Comment: See the second code block for an example of converting the numpy array to a byte string. pgmagick — which you're already using — supports jpg2000 so the example should work. If it doesn't, it likely means your installation of pgmagick was built without jpg2000 support.

Comment: Even the first line is not working, the error is shown in the opening post.

Comment: That's not an error I've seen specifically, so I'm not 100% sure the "right" way to address it, but the quick and dirty fix would be: `jpg_bytes = "".join(chr(x) for x in ds.pixel_array)`

Comment: Same as which? The "data type cannot be understood"? Can you copy+paste the exact code you're using and the exact error? (the quick fix I posted doesn't use any numpy methods so it's unlikely to cause a numpy error)

Comment: Ok, I added the complete function I use for converting the images in the OP, I hope that helps. And yes, I got the same error as before, even if there is no numpy involved.

Comment: You're still getting the same error because you've still got the same line in there:  `jpg_bytes = ds.pixel_array.astype('uint8').tostring()` :)

Comment: Even if I remove this line I get this error, so I don't think the problem is in that line.

Comment: Which line *is* causing the problem? Which line is shown in the stack trace?

Comment: The problem itself is appearently in one of the additional libraries (pydicom), and not from my code. I think I have to modify the library itself a bit...